# Regular expression validator accept decimal numbers 0 or 5

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm trying to write a Regular Expression validator. It should accept numbers only with decimal part 0 or 5 only.
like,

**Valid Numbers**
0.5
1 (1.0)
1.5
2 (2.0)
2.5
 . . . etc.

**Invalid Numbers**
0.1
1.2
1.3
2.4
2.6

please help me... Thanks.

Comment: Why is 2.5 both a valid and an invalid number?

Comment: Sorry, by mistake. 2.5 is valid number.

Comment: Do you want to accept all digits from all languages and cultures (`\d`), or only the digits 0-9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[0-9]+(\.[05])?$
```

The (...)? means that the decimal part is  optional.

Comment: Thanks, it works.How I can include .5 0r 1.00 or 2.00 etc as acceptable in this expression.

Answer (score 4):

```
^\d+(?:\.[05]0?)?$
```

works, but also allows leading zeroes like `00001.0`. Is that OK?

If not, use

```
^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.[05]0?)?$
```

This allows `0`, `123`, `0.00`, `1.5`, `2.50` etc. but rejects `00`, `1.2`, `1.500`, `-1` or `.5`.

Comment: @Remya: My updated version also allows trailing zeroes now as you requested in your comment to Mark's answer.

Comment: One doubt also, here how I can limit decimal numbers to 2 only. That means 2.00 or 2.50 only not 2.000 or 2.500.

Comment: @Remya: I've edited my answer. A tip for future questions: Details like these are important when constructing a regex, so you should include that information in your question instead of making us guess. Thanks.